# Why is universality of CFG undecidable?

Tags: computability, undecidability

Let $\text{ALL-CFG} = \{\left<G\right> \mid G\text{ is a CFG and } L(G) = \Sigma^*\}$.

I have understood the proof of ALL-CFG is undecidable, but I wonder why the following proof is not appropriate.

Let $C$ be a CFG. Then $\bar{C}$ is a CFG by closure under complement. Since the emptiness of CFG is decidable, we can use it to decide whether $\bar{C}$ is empty and therefore whether $C$ is universal.

This problem has confused me a lot. Really appreciate your help. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context-free languages are not closed under complement. For example, $\overline{\{a^nb^nc^n : n \geq 0\}}$ is context-free, but its complement isn't.

Comment: Sorry for my silly question. Thank you very much!

Comment: @いいな, Moreover, even if it were closed under complement, it wouldn't mean that you could find $\bar C$ for a given $C$. Also, since this answer answers your question, please consider accepting it.

Comment: @Dmitry, You are right. I mistook CFL for DCFL just now. Thank you for reminding me.